# How do I go back to the main Class after jumping to another one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am currently working on a GUI using Python 3.6 and PyQt5.

With the menu bar i open a popup, but when it closes, it is stuck in the other class. How can I go back to my main class? I'm including some relevant pieces of my code. Everything works fine until I click the menu item and the popup opens, after I click on the date I want, it closes and I get errors like `MyPopup` object has no attribute '(atribute name)'

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import xlrd
import datetime

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(1580, 1020)
        MainWindow.setDockNestingEnabled(False)


        import RAP_rc
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Register/logo2.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
#        MainWindow.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized)
        MainWindow.setWindowState(MainWindow.windowState() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimized | QtCore.Qt.WindowActive)
        MainWindow.setFocus(QtCore.Qt.PopupFocusReason)
#        MainWindow.activateWindow()
        MainWindow.raise_()
        self.statusbar.showMessage('User: Test')
        self.actionCargar_Archivo_Base.triggered.connect(self.getxlsbase)
        self.actionCargar_Archivo_Facturacion.triggered.connect(self.getxlsfacturacion)
        self.actionCargar_Archivo_Salesforce.triggered.connect(self.getxlssf)
        self.actionSeleccionar_Fecha.triggered.connect(self.openPopUp)
        if self.actionSeleccionar_Fecha.isChecked():
            date_text = str(date_select)
            print(date_select)
            self.label.setText(date_text)

    def openPopUp(self):
        self.pop = MyPopup()
        self.pop.show()

    def date_filter(self):
        self.main = Ui_MainWindow.setupUi(self, MainWindow)
        self.main.show()
        date_text = str(date_select)
        print(date_select)
        self.label.setText(date_text)



class MyPopup(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        import RAP_rc
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/Register/logo2.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.setFixedSize(392, 241)
        self.setWindowTitle('Fecha')
        self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self)
        self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 392, 241))
        self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
        self.calendarWidget.clicked.connect(self.select_date)



    def select_date(self):
        global date_select
        date_select=self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().toPyDate()
        selected_month = date_select.month
        selected_year = date_select.year
        print('Month ', selected_month, '\n', 'Year ', selected_year)
        self.close()
        Ui_MainWindow.date_filter(self)
        return date_select

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

you can see the full code here
https://github.com/liesugahara/Practicas/blob/master/Test

Comment: Your code throws me many errors since several things are not defined, if you want help you must provide a [mcve], that code has to be complete in the sense that you do not need anything else to execute it but as I point out yours is not.

Comment: I just added a github link to the full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the `date_filter (self)` method in the `Test.py` module.

```
    def date_filter(self):
##        self.main = Ui_MainWindow.setupUi(self, MainWindow)     # ---
##        self.main.show()                                        # ---
        date_text = str(date_select)
        print(date_select)
##        #self.label.setText(date_text)                          # ---
        ui.label.setText(date_text)                               # +++
```

[image]

Comment: If i want to print or use `self.datasf`from the ui class, how should i do it?

Comment: @Lie Sugahara  If my example helped you with something, do not forget to mark my answer as useful.

Comment: `self.datasf` this `<class 'list'>` `[['x', 'y', 'max'], [1.0, 0.0, ''], [2.0, 563.0, ''], [3.0, 0.0, ''], [4.0, 22000.0, ''], [5.0, 131.0, ''], [6.0, 475.0, ''], [7.0, 0.0, ''], [8.0, 15.0, ''], [9.0, 0.0, ''], [10.0, 282.0, ''], [11.0, 0.0, ''], [12.0, 0.0, ''], [13.0, 395.0, ''], [14.0, 563.0, ''], [15.0, 563.0, 22000.0]]`

Comment: self.datasf[0] -> ['x', 'y', 'max'],    self.datasf[0][0] -> 'x'